# Socket Connections Windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows, sockets

I have a Client Server application written in C#

The server listens on a specified port. A client pushes data to this server and the remaining clients pull this data. Likewise all the clients use this server.

I wanted to know, is there any cap on the number of connections that a socket can allow with reliable communication of data, as-in without data loss? Typical size of the data that is communicated to the server and then relayed to the clients is around 40 kbps.

Can you please help me understand what all parameters should be considered for designing such a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upstream bandwidth will be your biggest bottleneck. 
If by "40 kbps" you mean kilo-BITS per second instead of kilo-BYTES per second then that gives you 5 KB/s. If your upstream bandwidth is 1 mega-BIT per second (128 kilo-BYTES per second) then you can only have around (128/5) 25 clients.

For the allowing many connections on one port issue, HTTP servers do this without a problem.

Answer (score -1):

Actually one socket will not handle all the data in the server. In the server you have a listen socket which only purpose is to accept incoming connections from your clients. Then you get one connection/socket per client.

The operating system will try to evenly distribute the bandwidth among all connected sockets (yours and other applications). UDP sockets have higher priority than TCP sockets.

The server can treat as many clients as you like as long as the network bandwidth can handle it. If got got a few clients you can use threads for the sockets/clien t, while if you got many I suggest you read up on asynchronous handling (the BeginXX/EndXX methods).

If bandwidth is a problem you should throttle the sends and receives (the easiest approach is to use Thread.Sleep) to not choke the network connection.